# Google Cloud Function execution time increases with more active instances

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, execution-time

I have a python function that I would like to be able to simultaneously have several hundred instances running.  However, it seems like the execution time goes up the more instances I run.  When I run a single one, it take ~300 seconds.  When I run 100 of them, they take the full 540 second cloud function max and some of them time out.

I have checked the following things already:
   I am not exceeding my GHz sec per 100 seconds quote
   I only have the dependencies below
   I made sure I am deleting my temp files so I am not causing cold restarts.

Any ideas on what else may be causing longer execution time as I run more instances?  In theory, cloud functions should be have the CPU resources committed to each instance so I should not see longer execution times with more instances.

- pandas >= 0.25.3
- apache-libcloud >= 2.8.0
- cryptography >= 2.8
- tables >= 2.3.0

Comment: Without seeing the code, and how you measured the performance, it'll be impossible to say more than how Cloud Functions works, which is what Doug answered below. Consider adding a [minimal, complete reproduction of the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

The total execution time of a function is not simply gated by CPU power.  There is a cold start time for spinning up a new server instance, and multiple instances will not necessarily all spin up at the same time.  The system will gradually create new server instances as load increases.  This is not behavior you can control in any significant way; you can't eliminate the cost of a cold start, and you can't specify how fast it should scale.

If you sustain load on the function, the existing server instances will be reused, and the average execution time will drop, but you will necessarily observe some latency on scaling up.